# Jetty Http2 Client SSL connection timeout

Tags: jetty, http2, alpn

Setup: Spring Boot 1.4.1

Maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.http2</groupId>
        <artifactId>http2-client</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.6.v20170531</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-io</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.6.v20170531</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.6.v20170531</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-http</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.6.v20170531</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-http</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.6.v20170531</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-alpn-client</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.6.v20170531</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.alpn</groupId>
        <artifactId>alpn-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3.v20160715</version>
    </dependency>
```

The SSL Factory:

```
public static SslContextFactory createSslContextFactory(String trustKeyStorePath, String trustKeyStorePass, String keyStorePath, String keyStorePass, String keyManagerPass) throws Exception {
//      logger.info("Creating SSL factory");
        System.out.println("Creating SSL factory");
        SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory(true);
        try (FileInputStream trustKeyStoreStream = new FileInputStream(trustKeyStorePath);
                FileInputStream keyStoreStream = new FileInputStream(keyStorePath)) {
            KeyStore truststore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            truststore.load(trustKeyStoreStream, trustKeyStorePass.toCharArray());
            keystore.load(keyStoreStream, keyStorePass.toCharArray());
            sslContextFactory.setTrustAll(false);
            sslContextFactory.setTrustStore(truststore);
            sslContextFactory.setKeyStore(keystore);
            sslContextFactory.setKeyManagerPassword(keyManagerPass);

        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
//          logger.error("Keystore error", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        } catch (IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException e) {
//          logger.error("Key loading error", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
        return sslContextFactory;
    }
```

The connection snippet:

```
this.client = new HTTP2Client();
            client.setIdleTimeout(-1);//disable client session timeout
            try {
                client.addBean(this.sslContextFactory);
                client.start();
                System.out.println("Connecting on " + this.host + ":" + this.port);
                FuturePromise<Session> sessionPromise = new FuturePromise<>();
                client.connect(sslContextFactory, new InetSocketAddress(this.host, this.port), new NEADSessionListener(clientInstanceName, this), sessionPromise);
                this.session = sessionPromise.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            } catch (...) {
```

I am running using

```
-Xbootclasspath/p:/path/to/alpn-boot-8.1.10.v20161026.jar
```

which is the appropriate version for my JVM.

The result is

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.FuturePromise.get(FuturePromise.java:130)
```

Setting the jetty logger on debug didn't help much, the last logged items are:

```
2017-07-21 04:44:51.483 DEBUG 18323 --- [tp1224347463-26] org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest        : FillInterest@673fa7d3{true,SSLC.NBReadCB@29ab178d{SslConnection@29ab178d{NOT_HANDSHAKING,eio=-1/-1,di=-1}=>ALPNClientConnection@474a457e<-SocketChannelEndPoint@390cc1df{nead.2.addr/10.203.6.184:9443<->/192.168.111.11:41652,OPEN,fill=FI,flush=-,to=0/-1}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->SslConnection@29ab178d{NOT_HANDSHAKING,eio=-1/-1,di=-1}=>ALPNClientConnection@474a457e}} register SSLC.NBReadCB@29ab178d{SslConnection@29ab178d{NOT_HANDSHAKING,eio=-1/-1,di=-1}=>ALPNClientConnection@474a457e<-SocketChannelEndPoint@390cc1df{nead.2.addr/10.203.6.184:9443<->/192.168.111.11:41652,OPEN,fill=FI,flush=-,to=0/-1}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->SslConnection@29ab178d{NOT_HANDSHAKING,eio=-1/-1,di=-1}=>ALPNClientConnection@474a457e}
2017-07-21 04:44:51.483 DEBUG 18323 --- [tp1224347463-26] org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint     : changeInterests p=false 0->1 for SocketChannelEndPoint@390cc1df{nead.2.addr/10.203.6.184:9443<->/192.168.111.11:41652,OPEN,fill=FI,flush=-,to=0/-1}{io=0/1,kio=0,kro=1}->SslConnection@29ab178d{NOT_HANDSHAKING,eio=-1/-1,di=-1}=>ALPNClientConnection@474a457e
2017-07-21 04:44:51.484 DEBUG 18323 --- [tp1224347463-26] org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector     : Queued change CEP:SocketChannelEndPoint@390cc1df{nead.2.addr/10.203.6.184:9443<->/192.168.111.11:41652,OPEN,fill=FI,flush=-,to=0/-1}{io=0/1,kio=0,kro=1}->SslConnection@29ab178d{NOT_HANDSHAKING,eio=-1/-1,di=-1}=>ALPNClientConnection@474a457e:runUpdateKey:NON_BLOCKING on org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector@1ed1993a id=0 keys=1 selected=0
2017-07-21 04:44:51.484 DEBUG 18323 --- [tp1224347463-29] org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector     : Selector loop woken up from select, 0/1 selected
2017-07-21 04:44:51.484 DEBUG 18323 --- [tp1224347463-26] org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection   : onFillable exit DecryptedEndPoint@51fd3eea{nead.2.addr/10.203.6.184:9443<->/192.168.111.11:41652,OPEN,fill=FI,flush=-,to=1/-1}->ALPNClientConnection@474a457e->SocketChannelEndPoint@390cc1df{nead.2.addr/10.203.6.184:9443<->/192.168.111.11:41652,OPEN,fill=FI,flush=-,to=1/-1}{io=0/1,kio=0,kro=1}->SslConnection@29ab178d{NOT_HANDSHAKING,eio=-1/-1,di=-1}=>ALPNClientConnection@474a457e
2017-07-21 04:44:51.484 DEBUG 18323 --- [tp1224347463-29] org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector     : Running action CEP:SocketChannelEndPoint@390cc1df{nead.2.addr/10.203.6.184:9443<->/192.168.111.11:41652,OPEN,fill=FI,flush=-,to=1/-1}{io=0/1,kio=0,kro=1}->SslConnection@29ab178d{NOT_HANDSHAKING,eio=-1/-1,di=-1}=>ALPNClientConnection@474a457e:runUpdateKey:NON_BLOCKING
2017-07-21 04:44:51.484 DEBUG 18323 --- [tp1224347463-26] o.e.j.u.t.Invocable$InvocableExecutor    : org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable$InvocableExecutor@5b99f42f invoked CEP:SocketChannelEndPoint@390cc1df{nead.2.addr/10.203.6.184:9443<->/192.168.111.11:41652,OPEN,fill=FI,flush=-,to=1/-1}{io=0/1,kio=0,kro=1}->SslConnection@29ab178d{NOT_HANDSHAKING,eio=-1/-1,di=-1}=>ALPNClientConnection@474a457e:runFillable:BLOCKING
2017-07-21 04:44:51.484 DEBUG 18323 --- [tp1224347463-26] o.e.j.u.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill   : EatWhatYouKill@1f3f4916/org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer@794cb805/PRODUCING/1/1 produce exit
2017-07-21 04:44:51.484 DEBUG 18323 --- [tp1224347463-29] org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint     : Key interests updated 0 -> 1 on SocketChannelEndPoint@390cc1df{nead.2.addr/10.203.6.184:9443<->/192.168.111.11:41652,OPEN,fill=FI,flush=-,to=1/-1}{io=1/1,kio=1,kro=1}->SslConnection@29ab178d{NOT_HANDSHAKING,eio=-1/-1,di=-1}=>ALPNClientConnection@474a457e
2017-07-21 04:44:51.484 DEBUG 18323 --- [tp1224347463-26] o.e.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool   : ran EatWhatYouKill@1f3f4916/org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer@794cb805/PRODUCING/1/1
2017-07-21 04:44:51.484 DEBUG 18323 --- [tp1224347463-29] org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector     : Selector loop waiting on select
```

Note that the connection to the same server, using the same keys, is working from another software.

Comment: There is not enough information. Is the server correctly configured to run HTTP/2 ? If you can easily reproduce, can you please open an issue at https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues and attach a reproducible test case ? Thanks !

Comment: Thanks. Figured out eventually that it was just the way we loaded the project. The IDE was adding -Xbootclasspath at the end instead of before -jar .... It would be nice though if the error thrown by the client was a little more specific, since, obviously, it was unable to negotiate the connection in the absence of ALPN.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the order of Java switches was the cause of the issue -- more specifically, `-Xbootclasspath/p:/path/to/alpn-boot-8.1.10.v20161026.jar` needs to go before anything else, definitely before `-jar program.jar`.